# About the list of URIs showing the most errors

Tags: google-app-engine

In my application, I hava a cron job which runs every 30 mins.

My question is why GAE always say that it occurs erros.

[image]

However, when I go to see the LATEST log.

[image]

I cannot see any errors.

And when I query logs with minimum severity(error).

The latest error is happened several days ago.

How can I fix it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'Minimum severity' refers to the log level severity. HTTP status codes are different. In this case, your handler is returning a 405 (Method Not Allowed), but not logging any 'error' level log messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http status code being returned is `405`. I Think any non `2XX` codes will count as errors on that screen.

A 405 status means "Method Not Allowed"

I'm guessing that your RequestHandler for your cron task is not setup to receive `POST` requests.